# How to use Count with Case When?

Tags: sql-server, count, case, case-when

I am trying a Query to get Env between 2 dates.

If there is more than 1 value in the table : display error' else display the value of Env.

I am not sure if my query is correct.

```
SELECT ENV,
Case count(Env)
when 1 then Env
else 'ERROR'

From EnvTable
Inner JOIN USER ON USR_ID=Env_Usr_ID
where Usr_login='ELLA' and Env_Date between 201601 and 201612
Group by Env
```

i excpect Env, but the actual result is a message error: 
error converting data type varchar to numeric

Answer (score 1):

All branches of a `case` must return the same data type.  For example, to have all branches return a `varchar(max)`:

```
case count(Env)
when 1 then cast(env as varchar(max))
else 'ERROR'
end
```

Comment: Using varchar(max) is an overkill. Use a shorter length. I believe the longest numeric value should fit in a varchar(40)

Comment: Thank you for your message.  unfortunately, i am getting 2 columns  with 2 values 500 and 600 (wich is not the purpose of my query) and the second column display the message 'Error'.

Comment: @LuisCazares: `varchar(max)` uses the length of the string plus 2 bytes ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))  There's no reason to guess maximums anymore.

Comment: There shouldn't be any guessing if you know the data type of the column being converted. The documentation also states that MAX should only be used if the length will exceed the 8000 bytes, which won't happen with any numeric value.

Comment: From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Each non-null varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) column requires 24 bytes of additional fixed allocation which counts against the 8,060 byte row limit during a sort operation.

Comment: @LuisCazares: Interesting, it seems that in rather rare cases there is a performance penalty. For myself, having worked with Postges `text` type, size-limited strings and their truncate problems feel rather archaic.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this following script hint will help you resolve your issue. If I get your actual data sample from table 'EnvTable' & 'User', I can then provide the actual script.

```
SELECT 
E.ENV,
CASE COUNT(E.Env)
    WHEN 1 THEN CAST(E.Env AS VARCHAR(50))
    ELSE 'ERROR'
END AS ENV_COUNT
FROM EnvTable E
INNER JOIN [USER] U 
    ON U.USR_ID=E.Env_Usr_ID
WHERE U.Usr_login='ELLA' 
AND E.Env_Date BETWEEN '201601' AND '201612'
GROUP BY E.Env
```

Comment: Actually, is giving me 2 values. I want to have One value, this is the purpose. IF there is 2 values the error message should show but it's not the case now. Thank you for your help

Comment: In my query output, if "EnvTable" table has more than 1 records belongs to same "env" for "ELLA" from the given date range, its showing message 'ERROR' for that "env" value. Other case its showing the values directly from column "E.Env". Can you please explain if I am understanding the requirement wrongly.

Comment: It s right but i don't understand why i am getting the 2 records in the table and a column with message ERROR.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data from table "EnvTable" and "USER" along with your expected output? This will help more to reach the solution.

Comment: Hello i tried another way and i have the results but with the message error "Subquerry returned more than one value. This is not permitted when the subquerry follows =,!=, <,<=,>,>= or when the subquerry is used as an expression.

Comment: Here is my querry: IF (SELECT   distinct ( ENOBJ_ENV) 
 
FROM RES 
 INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR  ON USR_ID=  RES _USR_ID 
 where USR_LOGIN ='BELLA' and 
     RES_DATE_REM between  201601 and  201704 
 group by  ENV) >1
 SELECT    ENV  
 FROM RES   
  INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR  ON USR_ID=  RES _USR_ID 
 where USR_LOGIN ='BELLA' and 
     RES_DATE_REM between  201601 and  201704 
 group by  ENV
 ELSE
   print 'ERROR'

Comment: provide your sample data for both tables